# Вычисление последовательности чисел Фибоначчи

Tags: php, числа-фибоначчи, соревнование

Собственно суть соревнования в заголовке.

**Правила:**

- организатор соревнования в нём не участвует
- Язык программирования php

**Критерия победы**

- Победит тот алгоритм который вычислит самую длинную последовательность

**Тестирование**

- Предлагаю использовать этот сервис http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ для тестирования алгоритмов.

Comment: Странный критерий победы. Последовательность чисел Фибоначчи бесконечная.

Comment: Не похоже на вопрос ни разу, вот так.

Comment: @Visman А тэг соревнование ни о чём вам не говорит?

Comment: Самая длинная последовательность  без привлечение библиотек для больших чисел ограничивается самым большим числом в "чистом" PHP. При привлечении - та же картина, самым большим числом в библиотеке. В любом случае время работы алгоритма будет явно больше таймаута на запуск онлайн-скрипта.

Comment: @Naumov, нет. И еще минимум 4-м пользователям тоже.

Comment: @PinkTux В этом и условие т.е. победит тот кто сможет до окачания ограничения вывести самое большое число.

Comment: ну длинка на `php` это извращение. А код у 90% людей будет по скорости почти одинаков (без длинки). Дальше - `php` - не питон, длинки встроенной нет, а без неё - всё странно. Т.е. фактически соревнование - кто лучше складывает длинные числа. И да, а проверять как?

Comment: @pavel специально взял сервис с ограничениями http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ собственно у кого будет самое большое число тут и победит. В этом то и соль придумать самый лёгкий алгоритм.

Comment: @Naumov, в условиях подобного сервиса на чистоту замера времени влияет множество факторов. А здесь плюс-минус миллисекунда - уже разница в результате. В общем, чушь. Учитывая, что 99% тестируемого кода будут совпадать чуть ли не побайтно.

Comment: @PinkTux у задачи есть подводный камень - числа Фибаначчи слишком быстро растут, чтобы точно вычислить какое-нибудь число 2000 нужно эмулировать разряды - иначе мы не уберемся ни в целое, ни в число с плавающей точкой. На мой вкус задача довольно интересная.

Comment: @Naumov не успел днем ответить - работы много было, уже заминусовали, а вопрос действительно интересный...

Comment: @cheops твкое ощущение что мало кто знает матан из php программистов...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть множество способов вычислить число Фибоначчи, можно использовать определение и вычислять их последовательно. Однако, мне представляется наиболее продуктивный подход сначала создать функцию `fibanchi()`, вычисляющую произвольное число Фибоначчи по его номеру в последовательности. Самый быстрый способ решить эту частную задачу - формула Бине

```
<?php
function fibanchi($n) {
  return round((((1 + sqrt(5)) / 2) ** $n - ((1 - sqrt(5)) / 2) ** $n) / sqrt(5));
}
```

Однако, мало того, что формула сама по себе приближенная, при больших значениях числа Фибоначчи можно быстро выйти за границы как целого числа, так и числа с плавающей точкой. Если цель именно высшие значения чисел Фибоначчи и точность, можно организовать вычисления в массиве прямо по определению - долго, но зато получаемые значения будут очень точными (в этом случае можно замахнуться на числа 2000 и выше, заведомо недоступное при вычислении по формуле Бине с использованием скалярных типов).

```
<?php
function fibanchi($n) {
  // К-во разрядов
  $digit = intval($n / 4) + 5;
  $result = '';
  $a1 = [];
  $a2 = [];
  $a3 = [];
  $a1[0] = 1;
  $a2[0] = 1;
  for($j = 2; $j < $n; $j++)
  {
    for($i = 0; $i < $digit; $i++)
    {
      $a1[$i] = isset($a1[$i]) ? $a1[$i] : 0;
      $a2[$i] = isset($a2[$i]) ? $a2[$i] : 0;
      $b = intval(($a1[$i] + $a2[$i])/10);
      $a3[$i] = $a1[$i] + $a2[$i] - $b * 10;
      isset($a1[$i + 1]) ? $a1[$i + 1] += $b : $a1[$i + 1] = $b;
    }
    for($i = 0; $i < $digit; $i++)
    {
      $a1[$i] = $a2[$i];
      $a2[$i] = $a3[$i];
      $a3[$i] = 0;
    }
  }
  $flg = false;
  for($i = count($a2) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--)
  {
    if($a2[$i] >= 1) $flg = true;
    if($flg) $result .= $a2[$i];
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Для того, чтобы вывести последовательность можно воспользоваться циклом

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
  echo fibanchi($i)."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Каждое последующее число ряда **Фибоначчи** — это сумма двух предыдущих чисел.
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 …

Наверное, самый простой алгоритм.

```
$end = 25;
$j = 1;
for($i=1; $i<$end; $i+=$j) {
echo $i, ' ';
$j = $i - $j;
}
```

> 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21

Comment: последовательность начинаеться с 0 но в принципе и так сойдёт.