# Небольшое число Фибоначчи

Tags: javascript, числа-фибоначчи

> Дано целое число **1 ≤ n ≤ 40**, необходимо вычислить **n**-е число Фибоначчи (напомним, что **F[0] = 0, F[1] = 1** и **Fn = Fn−1 + Fn−2** при **n ≥ 2**).
>
> **Sample Input:**
>
> ```
> 3
> ```
>
> **Sample Output:**
>
> ```
> 2
> ```

Я попытался реализовать так:

```
function fib(n) {
    if (n < 1 || n > 40) return 1;
    var a = [0, 1];
    for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        a.push(a[i - 1] + a[i - 2]);
    }
    return a[n];
}
```

Если набить массив числами Фибоначчи по такому же условию, то он получается таким:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578, 5702887, 9227465, 14930352, 24157817, 39088169, 63245986, 102334155]
```

Но данное решение почему неправильно. Подскажите, где я допустил ошибку. Задача взята с сайта Stepic.org.

Comment: да попробуйте вы массив захардкодить `function fib(n) var a = [0,1,1,2 ...]; return a[n];`

Comment: @pavel я так делал. Не знаю почему, но при `a[20]` у меня выводит `6765`, а должен - `10946` .

Comment: http://ideone.com/5wjGMF возьмите отсюда массив.

Comment: @pavel хорошо, если не найду ошибку, то напишу)

Comment: А потом пишите в саппорт на этот сайт.

Comment: Да, скорее всего проблема внутри Stepic'a, т.к. все алгоритмы возвращают в 20 элементе массива 6765.

Comment: Уберите начальный ноль из массива

Answer (score 2):

Возможно проблема в том, что если Вашей реализации алгоритма передать число 41, что конечно же должно исключаться постановкой задачи, то оно вернет 1.

Что более вероятно, для платформы Stepic.org, может быть у Вас идет превышение лимита по памяти, поскольку Ваше решение создает массив для хранения всех чисел Фибоначчи, а по сути Вам нужны только два последних члена последовательности.

Попробуйте решение с использованием рекурсии, например, такое:

```
 function fib(n) {

     if(n == 1 || n == 2){
         return 1;
     }

     return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
 }
```

А если использовать такое решение?

```
function fib(n){
    if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    var prev = 1, current = 1;

    for(var i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
        temp = current;
        current = prev + current;
        prev = temp;
    }

    return current;
}
```

Похоже проблема не в алгоритме, а в системе проверки Stepic.org.
Реализация алгоритма на Python3 прошла проверку с первого раза:

```
def fib(n):

    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        return 1

    prev = 1
    current = 1

    for i in range(3, n + 1):
        temp = current;
        current = prev + current;
        prev = temp;

    return current
```

Comment: более вредного совета я представить не мог. При отсутствии оптимизации это порядка 2^N операций.

Comment: Мне нужен алгоритм, который работает меньше по времени, т.е. через массив, т.к. рекурсии работают очень долго

Comment: при использовании такого же алгоритма `a[20] = 6765`, т.е. у вас такая же ошибка, как и у меня (

Answer (score 1):

Вот одно из самых простых решений, по времени линейно от номера числа фибоначи, тоесть `O(n)` но зато память константа `O(1)` должно пройти все тесты

```js
function fib(n) {
  var a = 1, b = 1, c = 0;  
  for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    c = a + b; b = a; a = c;
  } 
  return n <= 2 ? (n == 1 || n == 2 ? 1 : 0) : c;
}

var n = 40;
for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
  console.log("fib("+i+") = " + fib(i));
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, он тоже не проходит тесты

Comment: @Артем странно вобще, можете показать пример теста на котором не проходит моё решение?

Comment: Вы можете сами попробовать [здесь](https://stepic.org/lesson/Числа-Фибоначчи-13228/step/6?course=Алгоритмы-теория-и-практика-Методы&unit=3414)  глава 2.2 задание 6.

Comment: @Артем ну какой тоест то не правильный ??

Comment: @Артем из за такой банальной и тривиальной задачи как то не особо хочется регистрироваться логиниться и т.д.

Comment: Полностью согласен, сам тест скрыт от посторонних глаз, но при каждой компиляции моего кода или вашего, выдает ошибку `Failed test #2. Wrong answer` .Больше никакого пояснения. Вот голову и ломаю.

Comment: @Артем да у них тесты наверняка неверные, бред какой то, напишите админам ихним пускай сверят свои тесты с [этой](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html) последовательность

Comment: Я немного посмотрел и у одного человека, тоже была такая же ошибка, как и у меня, на что ему руководитель ответил: "Вы привели правильные ответы при n >= 2. Но по условию n >= 1.". После чего я вообще ничего не понял. Все условия ведь правильны.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно потому, что число Фибоначчи до 40 вполне убирается в целое 32-битное число, поэтому его гораздо быстрее можно вычислить по аналитической формуле [Бине](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541310/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8/541439#541439)

```
function fibanchi(n) {
  return Math.round(
    ( Math.pow(((1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2), n) -
      Math.pow(((1 - Math.sqrt(5)) / 2), n)) / Math.sqrt(5));
}
console.log(fibanchi(40));
```

Comment: При `fibanchi(3)` выводит `4`, а должно `2`.

Comment: @Артем, спасибо, поправил.

Comment: так работает правильно, но платформа Stepic ругается ошибкой `Failed test #2. Wrong answer` .

Comment: думаю не стоит использовать дробную арифметику пока не "прижало",   вероятность получить погрешность здесь имхо выше.

Comment: @cheops тогда лучше использовать матричный вариант [xi xi+1] = [0,1]*[{0,1}{1,1}]^n и быстрое возведение в степень.

Comment: @cheops  математически формула точная, если бы не ошибки округления - давала бы правильный результат для любого n