# Как вычислить n число Фибоначчи?

Tags: c++, числа-фибоначчи

Дано целое число 1 <= n <= 40, необходимо вычислить n число Фибоначчи.

input: 3
output: 2

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

class Fibonacci {
 public:
  static int get(int n) {
    assert(n >= 0);
    // put your code here
    return n;
  }
};

int main(void) {
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  std::cout << Fibonacci::get(n) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что у вас вызвало затруднения?

Comment: почти дубликат - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/555691

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%87%d0%b8

Answer (score 0):

Хорошо попробуем так

```
function fib(n){
    if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    var prev = 1, current = 1;

    for(var i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
        temp = current;
        current = prev + current;
        prev = temp;
    }

    return current;
}
```

Comment: Ну разве что для *очень* небольшого числа `n` это работает...